# Odd Subject behavior: why does it act like my subscription was late?

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular component that I'm testing via Karma/Jasmine.  On the component, I have an observable following an element's scrolling:

```
const scroll$ = fromEvent(
      this.chatWindowElem!.nativeElement,
      'scroll'
    )
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
      );
```

On that observable, I create a Subject that is going to emit values as to whether a button shows/hides:

```
const showJumpSub = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
    this.showJumpToLatestButton$ = showJumpSub
      .pipe(
        startWith(false),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      );

    console.log('sub');
    scroll$
      .subscribe(($event: Event) => {
        console.log('sub fired');
        const show = this._calculateScrollDistanceFromBottom($event) > 50;
        showJumpSub.next(show);
      });
```

`this.showJumpToLatestButton$` is a public property on the component:

```
public showJumpToLatestButton$: Observable<boolean>;
```

This works perfectly fine when developing and playing with it, but once I get to unit testing it breaks.  I have this test:

```
fit('should emit \'true\' from jump button visible observable', async () => {
      // Arrange      
      const chat: Chat = new Chat();
      component.chat = chat;
      const scrollTarget = fixtureHelper.getElement('#merc-chat-window');
      
      spyOnProperty(scrollTarget, 'offsetHeight').and.returnValue(100);
      spyOnProperty(scrollTarget, 'scrollHeight').and.returnValue(200);
      spyOnProperty(scrollTarget, 'scrollTop').and.returnValue(49);

      fixture.detectChanges();

      const scrollEvent = new UIEvent('scroll', Object.assign({
        target: scrollTarget
      }));
        
      // Act
      console.log('dispatch');
      scrollTarget.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent);
      console.log('change detect');
      await fixtureHelper.runOnPushChangeDetection();
      console.log('change detect done');
      
      // Assert
      expect(fixtureHelper.getElement('#merc-jump-to-latest').hidden).toBeFalse();
    });
```

That test fails as the element I'm testing is still hidden though it shouldn't be.  With my `console.log`s, I get this output:

```
sub
dispatch
sub fired
change detect
change detect done
```

This shows that my subscription to the `Subject<boolean>` was created before I dispatched my test event which means my code *should* work.  However, I can only get this to work and pass if I change `Subject<boolean>` to `ReplaySubject<boolean>` which would seem to indicate there is a timing issue with my subscription.  But, the console logging with a `ReplaySubject` is exactly the same:

```
sub
dispatch
sub fired
change detect
change detect done
```

Can anyone shed a light on why exactly seemingly correct observable usage is giving seemingly incorrect results?

Comment: Hi Matt, can you define the subject at the top and then create an instance in the constructor? Maybe this could fix your issue? Mostly look like some hoisting issue

Comment: Are you using the default changeDetection strategy or on push?

Comment: I am using onPush

Comment: Angular is misbehaving - using BehaviorSubject to work around that is unfortunately the least bad workaround. The solution would be to have Angular use RxJS/Observables everywhere, for everything, but the devs don't want to in order to keep it beginner-friendly.